# Rails & AJAX, is there a reason you shouldn't render html view directly in controller action for ajax to process?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

The classic way to work with Rails & Ajax is always something that looks like this:

```
// JS - let's assume this submits to dummies#create
$(form).submit()

# Dummies Controller
def create
   @dummy = Dummy.new(dummy_params)
   respond_to do |format| 
     format.js
   end
end

# /views/dummies/create.js.erb
$("page").append("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'dummy_view' ) %>"); 

# /views/dummies/_dummy_view.html
<h1><%= @dummy.name %></h1>
```

I've always been curious, because the above seems to create a random `create.js.erb` file with very little meat... is there a reason (e.g., it's terrible convention, or terribly insecure or whatever), why you should NOT instead just render the view directly back to ajax?

```
// JS - basically takes responsibilites of create.js and puts it into the always
$.ajax(...).always(function(xhr, status){
    $("page").append($(xhr['responseText']))
    // responseText contains the partial rendered by the controller action
})

# Dummies Controller
def create
   @dummy = Dummy.new(dummy_params)
   render partial: 'dummy_view'
end

# /views/dummies/_dummy_view.html
# unchanged
<h1><%= @dummy.name %></h1>
```

NOTE above is pseudo-code, apologies for minor errors. The conceptual idea & question remain unchanged, though.

Comment: I thought it's because of supporting multiple formats, e.g. js, html, json, pdf ..., I'm glad to learn from other people's opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `create.js.erb` is not random, is the view for the action with the expected format.

Generally, you may not have a view so simple (You may have different selectors other than "page", you may have some extra js code to be executed after or before the append), a js view/script is the general solution for an ajax request to give the response full control over what to do.

You could have what you want, but it will just work for your particular case when the selector is always "page" and you only want to append html to that element. Nothing prevents you from doing that (though you might want to use a custom ajax request and not rails' one since it sets js format by default and executes the response's script).

The convention is that a rails' remote request renders a js script, you can move out of the convention if you want. You'll lose a lot of flexibility with your approach as is (like... what if the create action fails an you need to display errors?).

Comment: Got it thanks! Can you clarify with code example what you mean by this sentence: "(though you might want to use a custom ajax request and not rails' one since it sets js format by default and executes the response's script)"

Comment: When you use rails' helper methods with the option `remote: true` it executes specific rails js code that triggers an ajax submit with the format set to javascript, it then parses and executes the response body. If want to do what you want you wont be able to use rails' helper or you'll have to replace them with your own ajax calls https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actionview/app/assets/javascripts

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: ah yes in my case i'm using custom jquery `.ajax` and not `remote: true` for this reason